# Mongo DuplicateKey error despite no overlap

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a well-logged pool of several java servers behind an F5 load balancer (professionally managed, it's not sending traffic to >1 host) running Tomcat with my application installed, connecting to a sharded mongo cluster.  I'm using a base64-encoded SHA-1 hash of the primary natural key as the _id.  When a new record is to be created, I do a pretty basic:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("userId", userId);
query.put("_id", id);
DBObject user = getUsersCollection().findOne(query);

if (user == null) {
  getUsersCollection().insert(new UserObject(userId));
}
```

This is simplified.  In fact there are multiple checks for the pre-existence of this user, including one which should throw a custom exception, and none are triggered.  The traffic logs indicate a *single* incoming create request, and here's an example of what happens:

```
2014-01-19 20:03:45,167  [http-bio-7950-exec-827]:[...] : ERROR FATAL [...] - Internal server error
[...]: com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey: { "serverUsed" : "[...]" , "singleShard" : "replicaset_2/host1:27017,host2:27017,host3:27017" , "err" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: Users.$_id_  dup key: { : \"HASH\" }" , "code" : 11000 , "n" : 0 , "lastOp" : { "$ts" : 1390190614 , "$inc" : 1} , "connectionId" : 335764 , "ok" : 1.0}
```

Yet in my Users collection the record has been created:

**db.Users.findOne({_id:"HASH"}):**

```
{
  "_id" : "HASH",
  "createDate" : ISODate("2014-01-20T04:03:45.161Z"),
  ...
}
```

I'm pasting this as important because of the timestamps.  We have a timezone issue, but that aside I interpret the 6ms difference as clock skew between the mongo cluster and my application servers.  There is no other record of this incoming traffic (and it is logged as it bounces from server to server, even - nothing else!)  So I am 99.999% confident that my SINGLE LEGITIMATE insert call is both inserting and throwing an error.

Any theories as to how/why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.  I'll run tracers and examples if needed to answer questions with more information.

Comment: Looks like the literal word `HASH` is being set as the `_id` instead of a real hash.

Comment: That was just pseudocode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for a user using both `_id` and `userId` fields. Try to comment out this line: `query.put("_id", id);`.

It's not clear in your code where Java variable `userId` comes from. It's also not clear how `UserObject` sets an `_id` if at all.

Overall it looks like the way you search for user and the way you create him does not match, i.e. what defines a unique key on that user.

One fix could to replace these lines:

```
query.put("userId", userId);
query.put("_id", id);
```

with:

```
query.put("_id", userId);
```

To make `_id` field to be your `userId`.

Comment: Ah shoot, I forgot to make this more explicit in my description, since I thought it might come up.  I had to edit the code snippet to be less revealing, and I made a mistake in demonstrating a mismatch that isn't actually there.

Through testing millions of randomly generated ID's, I'm pretty sure that there is no risk of collisions on _id vs userId, and furthermore there cannot exist a user with one without the other in Mongo, there's no API that can do that.  But, I'll see if I can get this into testing anyway, to be 100% sure.  Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to use default `_id` as it is. You can make it to be any scalar type you want like ObjectID or Int or String.

Comment: You actually have a little race condition between the time you lookup your user and create a new one. You can use upsert if you want to create a user if it does not exist - it will be atomic.

Comment: It turns out that it's true.  My logging was turned down from what I thought, and that race condition was being hit, by a few mysterious double-calls in the same millisecond, even across different hosts!  So I need more error handling and to track down the cause, but at least I don't have to worry about the Mongo Java driver; oy.

Thanks very much, Aleksey! I really thought I'd dug all the way down on that, hope there're no hard feelings.